# Force redraw during sort function execution in order to animate the steps

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have been trying to make an animated bubble sort in JS but every time I run the code it goes from a random order to sorted instantaneously. How do I make it redraw and stall for a set amount of time after every time I swap two things in the array of colour codes.

```html
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"   width="300" height="700" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
<script>
function swap(nums, pos1,pos2) {
 var a = nums[pos1];
 nums[pos1] = nums[pos2];
 nums[pos2] = a;
}
function shuffle(nums) {
 for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random())*26);
  var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random())*26);
  swap(nums,num1,num2);
 }
}
function sleep(seconds) 
{
  var e = new Date().getTime() + (seconds * 1000);
  while (new Date().getTime() <= e) {}
}
function drawIt(nums) {
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(10, i * 20 + 10, 50, 20);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + nums[i] + ", " + nums[i] + ", " + nums[i] + ", 1)";
  ctx.fill();
 }
}
var nums = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i<=250; i+=10) {
 nums[i/10] = i;
}
shuffle(nums);
drawIt(nums);
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++) {
 for (var j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++) {
  if (nums[i] > nums[j]) {
   swap(nums, i,j);
   drawIt(nums);
  }
 }
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to use setTimeout() but nothing worked.

EDIT:

Is this what you meant because this still isn't working.

```html
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"   width="300" height="800" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
<script>
function swap(nums, pos1,pos2) {
 var a = nums[pos1];
 nums[pos1] = nums[pos2];
 nums[pos2] = a;
}
function shuffle(nums) {
 for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random())*26);
  var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random())*26);
  swap(nums,num1,num2);
 }
}
var counter1 = 0;
var counter2 = 1;
function drawIt(nums) {
 if (nums[counter1] > nums[counter2]) {
  swap(nums, counter1,counter2);
 }
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "1";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + nums[i] + ", " + nums[i] + ", " + nums[i] + ", 1)";
  ctx.rect(10, i * 15 + 10, 50, 15);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(10, i * 15 + 10, 50, 15);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + nums[i] + ", " + nums[i] + ", " + nums[i] + ", 1)";
  ctx.fill();
 }
 if (counter2 < nums.length) {
  counter2++;
 }
 else {
  counter1++;
  counter2 = counter1+1;
 }
}
var nums = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i<=250; i+=5) {
 nums[i/5] = i;
}
shuffle(nums);
drawIt(nums);
for (var i = 0; i < (nums.length*(nums.length-1)) / 2; i++) {
 setTimeout(drawIt(nums), 2000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll want to use a timeout, a while loop stops everything while the timeout allows other things to continue(your `sleep`, which you never use)

Comment: Please don't use that *sleep* function, it will freeze the browser for however long it runs so that nothing else happens.

Comment: @Lucas Brown :Regarding the edit: You have to let one iteration complete, before you set the timeout of the next iteration. You can not set all timeouts in a loop.

Comment: Where did you want to call this `sleep` from ? Tough it's still a bad idea, you could do it from a WebWorker : execute the algo in there, and only the drawing on the main thread. Your sleep function wouldn't be too much of an problem, since you'd be on a parallel thread, and the main one would be happy to render any time it receives an message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to force a draw, or DOM update, while your thread is still running. The way to solve this is to make your sort algorithm re entrant, so that it can be called from a timer, or via setTimeout. Each time the timer is triggered, you perform one iteration of the sort, and then draw the result.

This is a bit annoying sometimes when studying algorithms by visualizing them, as step visualization cannot be achieved without modifying the algorithm.

**EDIT:** Added working code snippet that implements a "reentrant" sort.

```html
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"   width="300" height="700" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
<script>
function swap(nums, pos1,pos2) {
 var a = nums[pos1];
 nums[pos1] = nums[pos2];
 nums[pos2] = a;
}
function shuffle(nums) {
 for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random())*26);
  var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random())*26);
  swap(nums,num1,num2);
 }
}
function sleep(seconds) 
{
  var e = new Date().getTime() + (seconds * 1000);
  while (new Date().getTime() <= e) {}
}
function drawIt(nums) {
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(10, i * 20 + 10, 50, 20);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + nums[i] + ", " + nums[i] + ", " + nums[i] + ", 1)";
  ctx.fill();
 }
}
var nums = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i<=250; i+=10) {
 nums[i/10] = i;
}
shuffle(nums);



function sort()
{    
    var i=0;
    var j=0;
    var sortComplete=false;
    var reentrantSort = function()
    {
        if (nums[i] > nums[j]){
            swap(nums, i, j);
            drawIt(nums)
        }
        j++;
        if (j == nums.length){
            j=0;i++;
            if (i == nums.length ) {
                i=0;j=0;
                sortComplete=true; //Sorting is done
            }
        }
        if (!sortComplete){ // If sort still not complete
            setTimeout(reentrantSort,40); // Run next iteration in 40 ms.
        }
    };
    reentrantSort();
}

sort();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would setInterval work as a substitute for setTimeout . The only thing I can think of that wouldn't be ideal about that is the fact that is goes on forever

Comment: Yes  @LucasBrown , setInterval is arguably better for this type of task in some cases. I am using setTimeout in the newly added example code, but it could easily be adapted to cancel the timer directly instead of using the Boolean flag.

Comment: @LucasBrown, I've added a working code-snippet that implements my suggested solution.

Comment: I wrote down a piece of code very similar to yours but it always came back with the same error message of  Maximum call stack size exceeded . Is there a way to combat this?

Comment: Not sure what you did, but exceeding the call stack probably means you are recursively calling a function an excessive amount of times. (Set-timeout prevents this by letting the function finish before the next event is triggered). You can use setTimeout with a timeout of 0, if you want the next iteration to run immediately after the previous one.

Comment: Did you mean like this

Comment: var bool = true;

 function animate() {

  if (nums[counter1] > nums[counter2]) {
   swap(nums, counter1,counter2);
   drawIt(nums);
  }

  counter2++;
  if(counter2 === nums.length){
   counter2=0;
   counter1++;
   if(counter1 === nums.legnth){
    counter1 = 0;
    counter2 = 0;
    bool = false;
   }
  }

  if(bool) {
   setTimeout(animate(), 2000);
  }

 }

Comment: You should only pass the name of the function reference as first parameter to setTimeout.  The way you wrote it you execute animate and pass the return value to setTimeout.    I.e. change setTimeout(animate(), 2000); to setTimeout(animate, 2000);

Comment: Your "reentrant" sort is a great conceptual idea - I would wrap the entire thing in a function again just to create a closure and isolate the variables.

Comment: @visibleman thank you for the advice it is working great and it animates just as planned thank you so much!

Comment: @MichaelChaney, thanks. Yes there are certainly room for improvement in regards to coding style. Since I wasn't sure about OP's JavaScript knowledge level. I thought it better to continue in the style that was already employed.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to separate concerns - i.e. sorting an array and rendering it's state at a given point are different problems - you could achieve this with an [ES2015 generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). In the following example I've taken a generic bubble sort function and added the `function*` signature and a `yield` statement - without modifying the algorithm this effectively allows you to step through each iteration in sequence.

```js
function* bubbleSequence(arr){
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        for(let j = 0, end = arr.length - i; j < end; ++j)
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
                let temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
                yield j+1; // <--- pauses execution
            }
}

function draw(arr, swapIdx){
    let ctx = document.getElementById('my-canvas').getContext('2d');
    arr.forEach((n, i) => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(i * 11 + 10, 10, 10, 40);
        ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${n},${n},${n},1)`;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(i * 11 + 10, 53);
        ctx.lineTo(i * 11 + 20, 53);
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = i === swapIdx || (i+1) === swapIdx ? '#f00' : '#333';
        ctx.stroke();
    });
}

var nums = [...Array(51)].map((_, i) => i * 5)
    .sort(_ => (Math.random() * 3 | 0) - 1);
var sorter = bubbleSequence(nums);
var interval = setInterval(_ => {
    let next = sorter.next();
    if(next.done) clearInterval(interval);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(_ => draw(nums, next.value));
}, 80);
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width=600 height=180></canvas>
```